# VBA to get plain text version of tracked changes in Word

Tags: vba, text, ms-word, contentcontrol

I have a rich text content control with a block of text that includes tracked changes (ie. edits while in Reviewing mode).

As part of a larger script, I need to store the raw plain text of this content control in a variable, with all tracked changes as normal text (regardless if it's insertion or deletion, so it's a jumble of random letters).

For instance, suppose I have the following original text in the content control: `spatiotemporal analysis of mesenchymal stem cell fate determination`.

I then edit the text manually with Reviewing mode on to capitalize all appropriate words such that the content control text is now:
`Spatiotemporal Analysis of Mesenchymal Stem Cell Fate Determination`.

If I manually expanded the tracked changes, I would see a series of crossed-out lowercase letters and associated uppercase letters in colour to show the edits:

> **S**<s>s</s>patiotemporal **A**<s>a</s>nalysis of **M**<s>m</s>esenchymal **S**<s>s</s>tem **C**<s>c</s>ell **F**<s>f</s>ate **D**<s>d</s>etermination

I want to store the following in a variable using VBA: "Sspatiotemporal Aanalysis of Mmesenchymal Sstem Ccell Ffate Ddetermination" (note that the strikethrough text and coloured text are now simply plain text.

Essentially, I wish to expand the tracked changes and then convert the rich text content control into a plain text content control. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you already try this in VBA?  If Yes did you run into a specific problem?